# how to create chekerboard using nth-child(odd&even) with 8x8 grid

Tags: html, css

i want to create checkerboard with display:grid 8 column and 8 row
using nth-child odd & even

```css
.papan {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8,50px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 50px);
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
   padding-top: 50px;
}
.papan div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.papan div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(185, 48, 48);
}
.papan div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 194);
}

.papan div:nth-child(odd):hover {
    background-color: black;
}
.papan div:nth-child(even):hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Papan Catur</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="papan">
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but the result is not checkerboard
i want the result like this

[image]

how can i make it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is like one of the many options for constructing an **8x8** checkerboard using a grid.

Use double and triple `nth-child()` to build sections with `background-color: rgb(40, 40, 194)` background:

```
:nth-child(-n + 8):nth-child(even),
:nth-child(n + 8):nth-child(-n + 16):nth-child(odd),
...
:nth-child(n + 57):nth-child(-n + 64):nth-child(odd)
```

This creates an interval.

For the rest of the cells (light), specify the background color `background-color: rgb(185, 48, 48)`, use the css rule as for everyone.

```css
.papan {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 50px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 50px);
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.papan div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(185, 48, 48);
}

.papan div:nth-child(-n + 8):nth-child(even),
.papan div:nth-child(n + 8):nth-child(-n + 16):nth-child(odd),
.papan div:nth-child(n + 17):nth-child(-n + 24):nth-child(even),
.papan div:nth-child(n + 25):nth-child(-n + 32):nth-child(odd),
.papan div:nth-child(n + 33):nth-child(-n + 40):nth-child(even),
.papan div:nth-child(n + 41):nth-child(-n + 48):nth-child(odd),
.papan div:nth-child(n + 49):nth-child(-n + 56):nth-child(even),
.papan div:nth-child(n + 57):nth-child(-n + 64):nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 194);
}

.papan div:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.papan div:nth-child(-n + 8):nth-child(even):hover,
.papan div:nth-child(n + 8):nth-child(-n + 16):nth-child(odd):hover,
.papan div:nth-child(n + 17):nth-child(-n + 24):nth-child(even):hover,
.papan div:nth-child(n + 25):nth-child(-n + 32):nth-child(odd):hover,
.papan div:nth-child(n + 33):nth-child(-n + 40):nth-child(even):hover,
.papan div:nth-child(n + 41):nth-child(-n + 48):nth-child(odd):hover,
.papan div:nth-child(n + 49):nth-child(-n + 56):nth-child(even):hover,
.papan div:nth-child(n + 57):nth-child(-n + 64):nth-child(odd):hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Papan Catur</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="papan">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>         
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```